# document.getElementsByClassName does not work

Tags: javascript

I'm a newbie in javascript and I can't get this to work:

content.js

```
var testing = document.getElementsByClassName("test")[0];
testing.style.color = "red";

alert('hi');
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="content.js"></script>

<div class="test">hi</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In fact, it won't even popup the alert message. If I remove the code above "alert('hi');", the alert works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: check ur path in script tag whether it is correct

Comment: Use the [browser console (dev tools)](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`) and read any errors.

Comment: @user3696882 The OP already said that the `alert` works without the erroneous DOM code.

Comment: change like this:<body>


<div class="test">hi</div>
<script src="content.js"></script>
</body>

Comment: Nathan Meunier, thank you! That was the problem. Thanks guys!